# Visualising opening hours of a building with rule-based symbology [QGIS]

Tags: qgis

I have the shapefile of a neighbourhood of buildings. Within the attribute table of this shapefile I have the opening and closing hours of each building, written in decimal format (e.g. 10:30am is 10.5, 5:00pm is 17). Opening and closing times are in their own real number fields each.

How can I create a rule-based symbology that shows those buildings that are open, from say 7am-9pm, if I have only the opening and closing time? How can I ask QGIS to compute the complete range of hours a given building is open for, and based on the values returned from that, return either a positive or negative for the purposes of symbology?

Comment: You should show us how your data are structured especially your opening hours (one line per building or in a more subtle structure?) ...

Comment: One line per building. Data is structured like so:

Building polygon ID,Opening hour weekday,Closing hour weekday  
ABC,8.5,21.0